# Autowiring Generic(T) Service in Controller within Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am a bit confused of how to autowire the Generic Service into Controller in Spring Boot 2.5.0.

Here is the code:
Main Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/classifiers")
public class ClassifierController<T> {
    protected static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
    public final T classifierService;
    protected final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter;
    protected final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;
    
    public ClassifierController(final JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter,
                                final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
                                final T classifierService) {
        this.jwtTokenFilter = jwtTokenFilter;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
        this.classifierService = classifierService;
    }
}
```

Extended Controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/ss01dictionary")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class SS01WasteDictionaryController
      extends ClassifierController<DictionaryService> {
    
    @Autowired
    public SS01WasteDictionaryController(JwtTokenFilter jwtTokenFilter,
                                         JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil,
                                         DictionaryService classifierService) {
        super(jwtTokenFilter, jwtTokenUtil, classifierService);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> getData(@RequestParam(value = "page", defaultValue = "0") int page,
                                                     @RequestParam(value = "size", defaultValue = "20") int pageSize) {
        PageRequest pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize);
        Page<Dictionary> dictionaryDTOList = classifierService.getAllDictionaryValues(pageable);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(dictionaryDTOList);
    }
...
```

Main Abstract Service:

```java
@Service
public abstract class ClassifierService {
    public final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
    public ClassifierService(final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }
    
    protected abstract Integer count();
}
```

Dictionary Service:

```java
@Service
public class DictionaryService
      extends ClassifierService {
    public DictionaryService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate);
    }
    
    public Page<DictionaryDTO> getAllDictionaryValues(Pageable page) {
        List<DictionaryDTO> result = jdbcTemplate.query(GET_SQL + " LIMIT " + page.getPageSize() + " OFFSET " + page.getOffset(),
                                                                 new DictionaryRowMapper());
        return new PageImpl<>(result, page, count());
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?
I want to have generic service with some abstract methods and generic controller.
How can I autowire the T service so that I have my methods for particular controller from particular service available?

Comment: What errors do you get? You haven't post any errors. For start I would propose not to annotate with `@Service` or `@RestController` your super/abstract classes

Comment: @pleft Hello! Sorry, errors is that No Beans for final T classifierService, in ClassifierController

Answer (score 0):

If you want to abstract out the common contents of controller and service in super abstract class then you have to mark the class as abstract and move this condition lower in hierarchy. The system is complaining rightly that it cannot find a service of type T because there is nothing to search by that name. If you create a class with name `T` this issue will most likely get resolved. Now, how to use generic definition here. Here how I have tried to do it.

- First create an abstract class of service say `AbstractService`
- create a concrete implementer of this service separately by qualifier if you want.
- create an abstract controller and tell that it will require a class which is a subclass of an `AbstractService`.
- In child controller inject required service and pass it to super class as you are doing.

Code below:

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service;

public abstract class AbstractTransporterService {

    final public String supportedVersion() {
        return "1.0";
    }

    public abstract String transport();
}
```

Impl1

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Qualifier("audioTransporterService")
public class AudioTransporterService extends AbstractTransporterService {
    @Override
    public String transport() {
        return "transporting audio details";
    }
}
```

Impl2

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Qualifier("videoTransporterService")
public class VideoTransporterService extends AbstractTransporterService {
    @Override
    public String transport() {
        return "transporting video details";
    }
}
```

Controller goes as below
AbstractController

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.controller;

import in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service.AbstractTransporterService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.Map;

public abstract class AbstractController<S extends AbstractTransporterService> {
    private final S service;

    public AbstractController(S service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public S getService() {
        return service;
    }


    @RequestMapping(path = "/version")
    public Map<String, String> controllerVersion() {
        return Map.of("type", getClass().getName(), "v", service.supportedVersion());
    }
}
```

Impl1

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.controller;

import in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service.AudioTransporterService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/audio")
public class AudioController extends AbstractController<AudioTransporterService> {


    public AudioController(AudioTransporterService service) {
        super(service);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        return getService().transport();
    }
}
```

Impl2

```
package in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.controller;

import in.silentsudo.autowiregenericservicecontroller.service.VideoTransporterService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/video")
public class VideoController extends AbstractController<VideoTransporterService> {

    public VideoController(VideoTransporterService service) {
        super(service);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String get() {
        return getService().transport();
    }
}
```

`@RestController` annotation information is not passed at runtime. So it is better not to annotate superclasses with this same goes for `Service`

Also path

- http://localhost:8080/audio/version
- http://localhost:8080/video/version

Are working as they are extending super class which has `/version` method

Source code https://gitlab.com/spring-boot-cloud-samples/autowire-generic-service-controller